# Warning: move_uploaded_file(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File() is not within the allowed path(s):

Tags: php, mysql, upload

i have a folder with events that upload a title, summary, content, date and image to a database. It's works fine so I duplicate the folder and only change the table of the database to do the same with a folder discounts, but it's doesn't work (it's not php.ini open_basedir restriction because in the other folder it's works fine), it shows this error when I upload a discount:

```
   Warning: move_uploaded_file(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File() is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/organizi/:/tmp/:/var/tmp/:/usr/local/php54/lib/:/usr/local/php54/lib/:/usr/local/php55/lib/:/usr/local/lib/php/) in /home/organizi/domains/organizing-erasmus.es/public_html/descuentos/classes/Article.php on line 112

Fatal error: Article::storeUploadedImage(): Couldn't move uploaded file. in /home/organizi/domains/organizing-erasmus.es/public_html/descuentos/classes/Article.php on line 113
```

Function storeuploadimage:

```
public function storeUploadedImage( $image ) {

    if ( $image['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK )
    {
      // Does the Article object have an ID?
      if ( is_null( $this->id ) ) trigger_error( "Article::storeUploadedImage(): Attempt to upload an image for an Article object that does not have its ID property set.", E_USER_ERROR );

      // Delete any previous image(s) for this article
      $this->deleteImages();

      // Get and store the image filename extension
      $this->imageExtension = strtolower( strrchr( $image['name'], '.' ) );

      // Store the image

      $tempFilename = trim( $image['tmp_name'] ); 

      if ( is_uploaded_file ( $tempFilename ) ) {
        if ( !( move_uploaded_file( $tempFilename, $this->getImagePath() ) ) ) 
        trigger_error( "Article::storeUploadedImage(): Couldn't move uploaded file.", E_USER_ERROR );

        if ( !( chmod( $this->getImagePath(), 0666 ) ) ) trigger_error( "Article::storeUploadedImage(): Couldn't set permissions on uploaded file.", E_USER_ERROR );
      }

      // Get the image size and type
      $attrs = getimagesize ( $this->getImagePath() );
      $imageWidth = $attrs[0];
      $imageHeight = $attrs[1];
      $imageType = $attrs[2];

      // Load the image into memory
      switch ( $imageType ) {
        case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
          $imageResource = imagecreatefromgif ( $this->getImagePath() );
          break;
        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
          $imageResource = imagecreatefromjpeg ( $this->getImagePath() );
          break;
        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
          $imageResource = imagecreatefrompng ( $this->getImagePath() );
          break;
        default:
          trigger_error ( "Article::storeUploadedImage(): Unhandled or unknown image type ($imageType)", E_USER_ERROR );
      }

      // Copy and resize the image to create the thumbnail
      $thumbHeight = intval ( $imageHeight / $imageWidth * ARTICLE_THUMB_WIDTH );
      $thumbResource = imagecreatetruecolor ( ARTICLE_THUMB_WIDTH, $thumbHeight );
      imagecopyresampled( $thumbResource, $imageResource, 0, 0, 0, 0, ARTICLE_THUMB_WIDTH, $thumbHeight, $imageWidth, $imageHeight );

      // Save the thumbnail
      switch ( $imageType ) {
        case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
          imagegif ( $thumbResource, $this->getImagePath( IMG_TYPE_THUMB ) );
          break;
        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
          imagejpeg ( $thumbResource, $this->getImagePath( IMG_TYPE_THUMB ), JPEG_QUALITY );
          break;
        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
          imagepng ( $thumbResource, $this->getImagePath( IMG_TYPE_THUMB ) );
          break;
        default:
          trigger_error ( "Article::storeUploadedImage(): Unhandled or unknown image type ($imageType)", E_USER_ERROR );
      }

      $this->update();
    }
  }
```

Admin.php file:

```
<?php

require( "config.php" );
session_start();
$action = isset( $_GET['action'] ) ? $_GET['action'] : "";
$username = isset( $_SESSION['username'] ) ? $_SESSION['username'] : "";

if ( $action != "login" && $action != "logout" && !$username ) {
  login();
  exit;
}

switch ( $action ) {
  case 'login':
    login();
    break;
  case 'logout':
    logout();
    break;
  case 'newArticle':
    newArticle();
    break;
  case 'editArticle':
    editArticle();
    break;
  case 'deleteArticle':
    deleteArticle();
    break;
  default:
    listArticles();
}


function login() {

  $results = array();
  $results['pageTitle'] = "Admin Login | Widget News";

  if ( isset( $_POST['login'] ) ) {

    // User has posted the login form: attempt to log the user in

    if ( $_POST['username'] == ADMIN_USERNAME && $_POST['password'] == ADMIN_PASSWORD ) {

      // Login successful: Create a session and redirect to the admin homepage
      $_SESSION['username'] = ADMIN_USERNAME;
      header( "Location: admin.php" );

    } else {

      // Login failed: display an error message to the user
      $results['errorMessage'] = "Incorrect username or password. Please try again.";
      require( TEMPLATE_PATH . "/admin/loginForm.php" );
    }

  } else {

    // User has not posted the login form yet: display the form
    require( TEMPLATE_PATH . "/admin/loginForm.php" );
  }

}


function logout() {
  unset( $_SESSION['username'] );
  header( "Location: admin.php" );
}


function newArticle() {

  $results = array();
  $results['pageTitle'] = "Nuevo Evento";
  $results['formAction'] = "newArticle";

  if ( isset( $_POST['saveChanges'] ) ) {

    // User has posted the article edit form: save the new article
    $article = new Article;
    $article->storeFormValues( $_POST );
    $article->insert();
    if ( isset( $_FILES['image'] ) ) $article->storeUploadedImage( $_FILES['image'] );
    header( "Location: admin.php?status=changesSaved" );

  } elseif ( isset( $_POST['cancel'] ) ) {

    // User has cancelled their edits: return to the article list
    header( "Location: admin.php" );
  } else {

    // User has not posted the article edit form yet: display the form
    $results['article'] = new Article;
    require( TEMPLATE_PATH . "/admin/editArticle.php" );
  }

}


function editArticle() {

  $results = array();
  $results['pageTitle'] = "Editar evento";
  $results['formAction'] = "editArticle";

  if ( isset( $_POST['saveChanges'] ) ) {

    // User has posted the article edit form: save the article changes

    if ( !$article = Article::getById( (int)$_POST['articleId'] ) ) {
      header( "Location: admin.php?error=articleNotFound" );
      return;
    }

    $article->storeFormValues( $_POST );
    if ( isset($_POST['deleteImage']) && $_POST['deleteImage'] == "yes" ) $article->deleteImages();
    $article->update();
    if ( isset( $_FILES['image'] ) ) $article->storeUploadedImage( $_FILES['image'] );
    header( "Location: admin.php?status=changesSaved" );

  } elseif ( isset( $_POST['cancel'] ) ) {

    // User has cancelled their edits: return to the article list
    header( "Location: admin.php" );
  } else {

    // User has not posted the article edit form yet: display the form
    $results['article'] = Article::getById( (int)$_GET['articleId'] );
    require( TEMPLATE_PATH . "/admin/editArticle.php" );
  }

}


function deleteArticle() {

  if ( !$article = Article::getById( (int)$_GET['articleId'] ) ) {
    header( "Location: admin.php?error=articleNotFound" );
    return;
  }

  $article->deleteImages();
  $article->delete();
  header( "Location: admin.php?status=articleDeleted" );
}


function listArticles() {
  $results = array();
  $data = Article::getList();
  $results['articles'] = $data['results'];
  $results['totalRows'] = $data['totalRows'];
  $results['pageTitle'] = "All Articles";

  if ( isset( $_GET['error'] ) ) {
    if ( $_GET['error'] == "articleNotFound" ) $results['errorMessage'] = "Error: evento no encontrado.";
  }

  if ( isset( $_GET['status'] ) ) {
    if ( $_GET['status'] == "changesSaved" ) $results['statusMessage'] = "Cambios guardados.";
    if ( $_GET['status'] == "articleDeleted" ) $results['statusMessage'] = "Evento eliminado.";
  }

  require( TEMPLATE_PATH . "/admin/listArticles.php" );
}

?>

classes/article.php file:

<?php

/**
 * Class to handle articles
 */

class Article
{
  // Properties

  /**
  * @var int The article ID from the database
  */
  public $id = null;


  /**
  * @var string Full title of the article
  */
  public $title = null;
  public $title_eng = null;

  /**
  /**
  * @var string The HTML content of the article
  */
  public $content = null;
  public $content_eng = null;

  /**
  * @var string The filename extension of the article's full-size and thumbnail images (empty string means the article has no image)
  */
  public $imageExtension = "";


  /**
  * Sets the object's properties using the values in the supplied array
  *
  * @param assoc The property values
  */

  public function __construct( $data=array() ) {
    if ( isset( $data['id'] ) ) $this->id = (int) $data['id'];
    if ( isset( $data['publicationDate'] ) ) $this->publicationDate = (int) $data['publicationDate'];
    if ( isset( $data['publicationDate_fin'] ) ) $this->publicationDate_fin = (int) $data['publicationDate_fin'];
    if ( isset( $data['title'] ) ) $this->title = $data['title'];
    if ( isset( $data['title_eng'] ) ) $this->title_eng = $data['title_eng'];
    if ( isset( $data['content'] ) ) $this->content = $data['content'];
    if ( isset( $data['content_eng'] ) ) $this->content_eng = $data['content_eng'];
    if ( isset( $data['imageExtension'] ) )  $this->imageExtension = $data['imageExtension'];
  }


  /**
  * Sets the object's properties using the edit form post values in the supplied array
  *
  * @param assoc The form post values
  */

  public function storeFormValues( $params ) {

    // Store all the parameters
    $this->__construct( $params );

    // Parse and store the publication date
    if ( isset($params['publicationDate']) ) {
      $publicationDate = explode ( '-', $params['publicationDate'] );

      if ( count($publicationDate) == 3 ) {
        list ( $y, $m, $d ) = $publicationDate;
        $this->publicationDate = mktime ( 0, 0, 0, $m, $d, $y );
      }
    }

     // Parse and store the publication date
    if ( isset($params['publicationDate_fin']) ) {
      $publicationDate_fin = explode ( '-', $params['publicationDate_fin'] );

      if ( count($publicationDate_fin) == 3 ) {
        list ( $y, $m, $d ) = $publicationDate_fin;
        $this->publicationDate_fin = mktime ( 0, 0, 0, $m, $d, $y );
      }
    }

  }


  /**
  * Stores any image uploaded from the edit form
  *
  * @param assoc The 'image' element from the $_FILES array containing the file upload data
  */

  public function storeUploadedImage( $image ) {

    if ( $image['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK )
    {
      // Does the Article object have an ID?
      if ( is_null( $this->id ) ) trigger_error( "Article::storeUploadedImage(): Attempt to upload an image for an Article object that does not have its ID property set.", E_USER_ERROR );

      // Delete any previous image(s) for this article
      $this->deleteImages();

      // Get and store the image filename extension
      $this->imageExtension = strtolower( strrchr( $image['name'], '.' ) );

      // Store the image

      $tempFilename = trim( $image['tmp_name'] ); 

      if ( is_uploaded_file ( $tempFilename ) ) {
        if ( !( move_uploaded_file( $tempFilename, $this->getImagePath() ) ) ) 
        trigger_error( "Article::storeUploadedImage(): Couldn't move uploaded file.", E_USER_ERROR );

        if ( !( chmod( $this->getImagePath(), 0666 ) ) ) trigger_error( "Article::storeUploadedImage(): Couldn't set permissions on uploaded file.", E_USER_ERROR );
      }

      // Get the image size and type
      $attrs = getimagesize ( $this->getImagePath() );
      $imageWidth = $attrs[0];
      $imageHeight = $attrs[1];
      $imageType = $attrs[2];

      // Load the image into memory
      switch ( $imageType ) {
        case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
          $imageResource = imagecreatefromgif ( $this->getImagePath() );
          break;
        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
          $imageResource = imagecreatefromjpeg ( $this->getImagePath() );
          break;
        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
          $imageResource = imagecreatefrompng ( $this->getImagePath() );
          break;
        default:
          trigger_error ( "Article::storeUploadedImage(): Unhandled or unknown image type ($imageType)", E_USER_ERROR );
      }

      // Copy and resize the image to create the thumbnail
      $thumbHeight = intval ( $imageHeight / $imageWidth * ARTICLE_THUMB_WIDTH );
      $thumbResource = imagecreatetruecolor ( ARTICLE_THUMB_WIDTH, $thumbHeight );
      imagecopyresampled( $thumbResource, $imageResource, 0, 0, 0, 0, ARTICLE_THUMB_WIDTH, $thumbHeight, $imageWidth, $imageHeight );

      // Save the thumbnail
      switch ( $imageType ) {
        case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
          imagegif ( $thumbResource, $this->getImagePath( IMG_TYPE_THUMB ) );
          break;
        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
          imagejpeg ( $thumbResource, $this->getImagePath( IMG_TYPE_THUMB ), JPEG_QUALITY );
          break;
        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
          imagepng ( $thumbResource, $this->getImagePath( IMG_TYPE_THUMB ) );
          break;
        default:
          trigger_error ( "Article::storeUploadedImage(): Unhandled or unknown image type ($imageType)", E_USER_ERROR );
      }

      $this->update();
    }
  }


  /**
  * Deletes any images and/or thumbnails associated with the article
  */

  public function deleteImages() {

    // Delete all fullsize images for this article
    foreach (glob( ARTICLE_IMAGE_PATH . "/" . IMG_TYPE_FULLSIZE . "/" . $this->id . ".*") as $filename) {
      if ( !unlink( $filename ) ) trigger_error( "Article::deleteImages(): Couldn't delete image file.", E_USER_ERROR );
    }

    // Delete all thumbnail images for this article
    foreach (glob( ARTICLE_IMAGE_PATH . "/" . IMG_TYPE_THUMB . "/" . $this->id . ".*") as $filename) {
      if ( !unlink( $filename ) ) trigger_error( "Article::deleteImages(): Couldn't delete thumbnail file.", E_USER_ERROR );
    }

    // Remove the image filename extension from the object
    $this->imageExtension = "";
  }


  /**
  * Returns the relative path to the article's full-size or thumbnail image
  *
  * @param string The type of image path to retrieve (IMG_TYPE_FULLSIZE or IMG_TYPE_THUMB). Defaults to IMG_TYPE_FULLSIZE.
  * @return string|false The image's path, or false if an image hasn't been uploaded
  */

  public function getImagePath( $type=IMG_TYPE_FULLSIZE ) {
    return ( $this->id && $this->imageExtension ) ? ( ARTICLE_IMAGE_PATH . "/$type/" . $this->id . $this->imageExtension ) : false;
  }



  /**
  * Returns an Article object matching the given article ID
  *
  * @param int The article ID
  * @return Article|false The article object, or false if the record was not found or there was a problem
  */

  public static function getById( $id ) {
    $conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
    $sql = "SELECT *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(publicationDate) AS publicationDate, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(publicationDate_fin) AS publicationDate_fin FROM descuentos WHERE id = :id";
    $st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
    $st->bindValue( ":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT );
    $st->execute();
    $row = $st->fetch();
    $conn = null;
    if ( $row ) return new Article( $row );
  }


  /**
  * Returns all (or a range of) Article objects in the DB
  *
  * @param int Optional The number of rows to return (default=all)
  * @param string Optional column by which to order the descuentos (default="publicationDate DESC")
  * @return Array|false A two-element array : results => array, a list of Article objects; totalRows => Total number of descuentos
  */

  public static function getList( $numRows=1000000, $order="id DESC" ) {
    $conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
    $sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(publicationDate) AS publicationDate, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(publicationDate_fin) AS publicationDate_fin FROM descuentos
            ORDER BY " . mysql_escape_string($order) . " LIMIT :numRows";

    $st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
    $st->bindValue( ":numRows", $numRows, PDO::PARAM_INT );
    $st->execute();
    $list = array();

    while ( $row = $st->fetch() ) {
      $article = new Article( $row );
      $list[] = $article;
    }

    // Now get the total number of descuentos that matched the criteria
    $sql = "SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS totalRows";
    $totalRows = $conn->query( $sql )->fetch();
    $conn = null;
    return ( array ( "results" => $list, "totalRows" => $totalRows[0] ) );
  }



  /**
  * Inserts the current Article object into the database, and sets its ID property.
  */

  public function insert() {

    // Does the Article object already have an ID?
    if ( !is_null( $this->id ) ) trigger_error ( "Article::insert(): Attempt to insert an Article object that already has its ID property set (to $this->id).", E_USER_ERROR );

    // Insert the Article
    $conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
    $sql = "INSERT INTO descuentos ( publicationDate, publicationDate_fin, title, title_eng, content, content_eng, imageExtension ) VALUES ( FROM_UNIXTIME(:publicationDate), FROM_UNIXTIME(:publicationDate_fin), :title, :title_eng, :content, :content_eng, :imageExtension )";
    $st = $conn->prepare ( $sql );
    $st->bindValue( ":publicationDate", $this->publicationDate, PDO::PARAM_INT );
    $st->bindValue( ":publicationDate_fin", $this->publicationDate_fin, PDO::PARAM_INT );
    $st->bindValue( ":title", $this->title, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $st->bindValue( ":title_eng", $this->title_eng, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $st->bindValue( ":content", $this->content, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $st->bindValue( ":content_eng", $this->content_eng, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $st->bindValue( ":imageExtension", $this->imageExtension, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $st->execute();
    $this->id = $conn->lastInsertId();
    $conn = null;
  }


  /**
  * Updates the current Article object in the database.
  */

  public function update() {

    // Does the Article object have an ID?
    if ( is_null( $this->id ) ) trigger_error ( "Article::update(): Attempt to update an Article object that does not have its ID property set.", E_USER_ERROR );

    // Update the Article
    $conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
    $sql = "UPDATE descuentos SET publicationDate=FROM_UNIXTIME(:publicationDate), publicationDate_fin=FROM_UNIXTIME(:publicationDate_fin), title=:title, title_eng=:title_eng, content=:content, content_eng=:content_eng, imageExtension=:imageExtension WHERE id = :id";
    $st = $conn->prepare ( $sql );
    $st->bindValue( ":publicationDate", $this->publicationDate, PDO::PARAM_INT );
    $st->bindValue( ":publicationDate_fin", $this->publicationDate_fin, PDO::PARAM_INT );
    $st->bindValue( ":title", $this->title, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $st->bindValue( ":title_eng", $this->title_eng, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $st->bindValue( ":content", $this->content, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $st->bindValue( ":content_eng", $this->content_eng, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $st->bindValue( ":imageExtension", $this->imageExtension, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $st->bindValue( ":id", $this->id, PDO::PARAM_INT );
    $st->execute();
    $conn = null;
  }


  /**
  * Deletes the current Article object from the database.
  */

  public function delete() {

    // Does the Article object have an ID?
    if ( is_null( $this->id ) ) trigger_error ( "Article::delete(): Attempt to delete an Article object that does not have its ID property set.", E_USER_ERROR );

    // Delete the Article
    $conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
    $st = $conn->prepare ( "DELETE FROM descuentos WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1" );
    $st->bindValue( ":id", $this->id, PDO::PARAM_INT );
    $st->execute();
    $conn = null;
  }

}

?>
```

Editarticle file:

```
<?php include "templates/include/header.php" ?>

      <script>

      // Prevents file upload hangs in Mac Safari
      // Inspired by http://airbladesoftware.com/notes/note-to-self-prevent-uploads-hanging-in-safari

      function closeKeepAlive() {
        if ( /AppleWebKit|MSIE/.test( navigator.userAgent) ) {
          var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.open( "GET", "/ping/close", false );
          xhr.send();
        }
      }

      </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://organizing-erasmus.es/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        tinymce.init({
            selector: "#content",
            plugins : 'link table insertdatetime textcolor',
            toolbar: "forecolor backcolor save",
            language: "es",
            tools: "inserttable"
        });
         tinymce.init({
            selector: "#content_eng",
            plugins : 'link table insertdatetime textcolor',
            toolbar: "forecolor backcolor save",
            language: "es",
            tools: "inserttable"
        });
    </script>
      <div id="adminHeader">
        <h2>Panel de administración de descuentos</h2>
        <p>Estás identificado como <b><?php echo htmlspecialchars( $_SESSION['username']) ?></b>. <a href="admin.php?action=logout"?>Salir</a></p>
      </div>

      <h1><?php echo $results['pageTitle']?></h1>

      <form action="admin.php?action=<?php echo $results['formAction']?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="closeKeepAlive()">
        <input type="hidden" name="articleId" value="<?php echo $results['article']->id ?>"/>

<?php if ( isset( $results['errorMessage'] ) ) { ?>
        <div class="errorMessage"><?php echo $results['errorMessage'] ?></div>
<?php } ?>

        <ul>

          <li>
            <label for="title">Título del descuento</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Nombre del descuento"  autofocus maxlength="15" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( $results['article']->title )?>" required/>
          </li>

           <li>
            <label for="title_eng">Título del descuento (inglés)</label>
            <input type="text" name="title_eng" id="title_eng" placeholder="Nombre del descuento en inglés"   maxlength="15" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( $results['article']->title_eng )?>" />
          </li>

          <li>
            <label for="content" class="content_label">Contenido del descuento</label>
            <textarea name="content" id="content" placeholder="Contenido HTML del descuento"    maxlength="100000" style="height: 30em;"><?php echo htmlspecialchars( $results['article']->content )?></textarea>
          </li>

          <li>
            <label for="content_eng" class="content_label">Contenido del descuento (inglés)</label>
            <textarea name="content_eng" id="content_eng" placeholder="Contenido HTML del descuento en inglés"  maxlength="100000" style="height: 30em;"><?php echo htmlspecialchars( $results['article']->content_eng )?></textarea>
          </li>


          <li>
            <label for="publicationDate">Fecha de inicio</label>
            <input type="date" name="publicationDate" id="publicationDate" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD"  maxlength="10" value="<?php echo $results['article']->publicationDate ? date( "Y-m-d", $results['article']->publicationDate ) : "" ?>" required/>
          </li>

        <li>
            <label for="publicationDate_fin">Fecha de fin</label>
            <input type="date" name="publicationDate_fin" id="publicationDate_fin" required="" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD"  maxlength="10" value="<?php echo $results['article']->publicationDate_fin ? date( "Y-m-d", $results['article']->publicationDate_fin ) : "" ?>" required/>
          </li>



          <?php if ( $results['article'] && $imagePath = $results['article']->getImagePath() ) { ?>
          <li>
            <label>Imagen actual</label>
            <img id="articleImage" src="<?php echo $imagePath ?>" alt="Article Image" />
          </li>

          <li>
            <label></label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="deleteImage" id="deleteImage" value="yes"/ > <label for="deleteImage">Eliminar</label>
          </li>
          <?php } ?>

          <li>
            <label for="image">Nueva imagen</label>
            <input type="file" name="image" id="image" placeholder="Choose an image to upload"  maxlength="255"/>
          </li>

        </ul>

        <div class="buttons">
          <input type="submit" name="saveChanges" value="Guardar cambios" />
          <input type="submit" formnovalidate name="cancel" value="Cancelar" />
        </div>

      </form>

<?php if ( $results['article']->id ) { ?>
      <p><a href="admin.php?action=deleteArticle&amp;articleId=<?php echo $results['article']->id ?>" onclick="return confirm('Eliminar este descuento?')">Eliminar este descuento</a></p>
<?php } ?>

<?php include "templates/include/footer.php" ?>
```

Config.php file (path image):

```
define( "ARTICLE_IMAGE_PATH", "images/articles" );
define( "IMG_TYPE_FULLSIZE", "fullsize" );
define( "IMG_TYPE_THUMB", "thumb" );
define( "ARTICLE_THUMB_WIDTH", 400 );
```

Comment: Are your permissions set correctly? `chmod -R 0777 discounts/` to make sure it ain't a permission problem.

Comment: Yes, it's have the correct chmod settings.

Comment: double-check that it is not open_basedir related. This error message indicates that it is. Are you sure that the path to your file is what you expect ? I think that your getImagePath method returns false, as the parenthesis in your error message are empty. They should contain the path to your file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the error message :

> File() is not within the allowed path(s):
>   (/home/organizi/:/tmp/:/var/tmp/:/usr/local/php54/lib/:/usr/local/php54/lib/:/usr/local/php55/lib/:/usr/local/lib/php/)
>   in
>   /home/organizi/domains/organizing-erasmus.es/public_html/descuentos/classes/Article.php
>   on line 112

The path to your file should appear in the parenthesis in the error message, like *File(/home/xxx/file.png) is not within the allowed path(s)* for example.
This means that the path to your file is empty, so check your getImagePath method, i suspect that it returned false instead of the path you expected.

Comment: Var_dump in $this->getImagePath() gives to me "bool(false), var dump in $this->id gives "string(1) "0"", var_dump in $tempFilename gives "string(14) "/tmp/phpUD1QM8""

Comment: $this->id = "0" means that a boolean evaluation of it will return false, that's why you have a bug. Since you get this value from the last insert id, i suspect that you forgot to make the id field auto increment.

Comment: Yes, it's solved now, the id field didn't have auto increment ;)